# Filter JSON Output with PHP

Tags: php, json, filter

I have been scratching my head for hours on this one and I just cant seem to get it to work.
I have a JSON Output like this example:

```
    {
    "response": {
        "dataInfo": {
            "foundCount": 494,
            "returnedCount": 4
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "10/03/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "10/03/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "152962",
                "modId": "3"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/14/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/06/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153228",
                "modId": "22"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/07/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/06/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153329",
                "modId": "7"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/08/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/08/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153513",
                "modId": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter this output using PHP by the Start_Date field and count how many were created in each month. I have got the results of the JSON into a array with JSON Decode.

```
$urls = $ref->multicurlRestApi($urllinkarray, $postfield, $headers);
            
            $decode_open = json_decode($urls[0],true);
```

For example the output of this would be as follows.

Month 10: 1

Month 11: 3

Any help is massively appreciated right now to save me going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by storing all months in a key-value-array, where the key is the month and the value to amount of entries in that month.

Now, loop through all entries (`$decode_open["response"]["data"]`) and calculate the month. I just converted the date to a UNIX Timestamp and then back with the PHP `date` function to get the month.

Then you just have to add the month to your array (if it doesn't already exist) and count it up.

```php
// Your code to get the data
$urls = $ref->multicurlRestApi($urllinkarray, $postfield, $headers);
$decode_open = json_decode($urls[0],true);

$months = []; // <- The array we store the final data in
$items = $decode_open["response"]["data"];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $month = date("m", strtotime($item["fieldData"]["Start_Date"]));
    if(!isset($months[$month])) $months[$month] = 0; // <- Add the month to the array if it doesn't exist
    $months[$month]++; // <- Increase the value for that month
}

print_r($months);
```

The output should be the following:

```
Array
(
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 3
)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, I have one more quick question about this.
The output gives me the following 
`Array ( [06] => 8 [07] => 6 [08] => 7 [09] => 15 [10] => 29 [11] => 5 )`

What if Instead of [MONTH] => VALUE

It showed a static name for that one for example [M1] => VALUE [M2] => VALUE ETC?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$jsonStr = <<<JSON
 {
    "response": {
        "dataInfo": {
            "foundCount": 494,
            "returnedCount": 4
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "10/03/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "10/03/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "152962",
                "modId": "3"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/14/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/06/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153228",
                "modId": "22"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/07/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/06/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153329",
                "modId": "7"
            },
            {
                "fieldData": {
                    "Closed_Date": "11/08/2021",
                    "Start_Date": "11/08/2021"
                },
                "portalData": {},
                "recordId": "153513",
                "modId": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
JSON;
$response = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
    return;
}
$counter = [];
foreach ($response['response']['data'] as $item) {
    $startDate = new DateTime($item['fieldData']['Start_Date']);
    $month = $startDate->format('m');
    if (key_exists($month, $counter)) {
        $counter[$month] += 1;
    } else {
        $counter[$month] = 1;
    }
}

var_dump($counter);die;
```

Comment: Whilst your code may solve the problem, it helps to add some explanation so that others can understand what you have done (and why).

Comment: thx for your advice, my english is not good